# How to change attribute type to String (WEKA - CSV to ARFF)

Tags: java, csv, weka, document-classification, arff

I'm trying to make an SMS SPAM classifier using the WEKA library. I have a CSV file with "label" and "text" headings. When I use the code below, it creates an ARFF file with two attributes:

```
@attribute label {ham,spam}
@attribute text {'Go until jurong point','Ok lar...', etc.}
```

Currently, it seems that the text attribute is formatted as a nominal attribute with each message's text as a value. But I need the text attribute to be a String attribute, not a list of all of the text from all instances. Having the text attribute as a String will allow me to use the StringToWordVector filter for training a classifier.

```
// load CSV
CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
loader.setSource(new File(args[0]));
Instances data = loader.getDataSet();

// save ARFF
ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver();
saver.setInstances(data);
saver.setFile(new File(args[1]));
saver.setDestination(new File(args[1]));
saver.writeBatch();
```

I know I can create a String attribute like this:

```
Attribute tmp = new Attribute("tmp", (FastVector) null);
```

But I don't know how to replace the current attribute, or set the attribute type before reading in the CSV.

I tried inserting a new String attribute and deleting the current nominal attribute, but this deletes all of the SMS text along with it. I also tried using [renameAttributeValue](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/Instances.html#renameAttributeValue%28weka.core.Attribute,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), but this doesn't seem to work for changing the attribute type.

**EDIT:**
I suspect that this [NominalToString filter](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/NominalToString.html) will do the job, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This did the trick. It changed the text attribute type, but not the label attribute type (though I'm not sure why it did one but not the other).

```
NominalToString filter1 = new NominalToString();
filter1.setInputFormat(data);
data = Filter.useFilter(data, filter1);
```

There's a small tip [here](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Text+categorization+with+WEKA#Import-CSV%20files)

> By default, non-numerical attributes get imported as NOMINAL
>   attributes, which is not necessarily desired for textual data,
>   especially if one wants to use the StringToWordVector filter. In order
>   to change the attribute to STRING, one can run the NominalToString
>   filter (package weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute) on the data,
>   specifying the attribute index or range of indices that should be
>   converted (NB: this filter does not exclude the class attribute from
>   conversion!).