# WEKA Convert attribute to string in CLI

Tags: java, string, command-line-interface, weka

I have the following [image: logfile]. In my arff, the requested content is an attribute.

```
@relation glastopf

@attribute Method {GET}
@attribute ContentRequested {/,/favicon.ico}
@attribute Malicious numeric

@data

GET,/,1
GET,/favicon.ico,0
GET,/favicon.ico,0
GET,/favicon.ico,0
```

How can I set the ContentRequested attribute to string so that WEKA compares strings not a set of string like `{/,/favicon.ico}` since content requested can be other than the one found in training file.

I know this is possible using [JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179879/how-to-change-attribute-type-to-string-weka-csv-to-arff) but how can I do this in CLI? Thankyou